# Check if a particular Python script is already running

Tags: python, operating-system, subprocess, pycharm

How can I check, from a Python script, if another specific Python script is running?

```
def running():
    for q in psutil.process_iter():
        print q
        if q.name() == 'server_class.py':
            return True
    return False
```

I have tried that but the program is called "python" and not the name of the script.

Comment: Do you control the other script? If so, you could use some form of inter-process communication to ask it if it's running..

Comment: *Nix: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/110698/how-to-check-which-specific-processes-python-scripts-are-running

Answer (score 2):

The python script file will be part of the command line. You can try something along these lines:

```
def running():

    for q in psutil.process_iter():
        if q.name() == 'python':
            print q.cmdline()
            if len(q.cmdline())>1 and 'server_class.py' in q.cmdline()[1]:
                return True

    return False
```

I am using `in` just for the example. You might want to match the full path.

Comment: I had to insert 'prozesslinie = q.cmdline()' and then test this for len. otherwise I got the error 'TypeError: object of type 'method' has no len()'

Comment: I have adjusted the example

Comment: Not working for Django App. It's weird : only my scheduled `CRONS` show in the list. In another chrome tab, I got a `views.py` running a long function but it doesn't show.

Answer (score -1):

**Case:** *When you want to exit the script, if a previous instance is already running:*

```
def already_running(script_name):
num_instance = 0
for q in psutil.process_iter():
    if 'python' in q.name():
        if len(q.cmdline()) > 1 and script_name in q.cmdline()[1]:
            num_instance += 1
return num_instance > 1
```

**What it does:**

1. It checks for the number of instances of the `script_name` currently running. If you are calling this from file `xyz.py` and sending `xyz.py` as argument, remember the current instance will also be counted
2. If `num_instance` > 1, you have a previous instance running.

Hope this is useful.

Comment: Thx for the idea. Yet, `q.cmdline()` is returning a list with all the parameters the python binary was executed with. Relying on the scriptname being in slot [1] is prone to error. I have a version posted here https://stackoverflow.com/a/77737574/4311316