# How to check if Python script is already running

Tags: python

I have python script on Ubuntu, which sometimes running more than 24 hours. I have set in cron, to run this script every day. However if script is still running, I would like to terminate new instance of this script. I have already found some solution, but they seems to be complicated. I would like to add few lines in the beginning of script, which will be checking if the script is running, if yes return, else continue.

I like this command:

```
pgrep -a python | grep 'script.py'
```

it is possible to make some smart solution for this problem?

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/788411/check-to-see-if-python-script-is-running

Answer (score 2):

There is no simple way how to do it. As mentioned in comments you can use creation of some locking file. But i prefer use of sockets. Not sure if it works same on Linux but on Windows i use this:

```
import socket

class AppMutex:
    """
    Class serves as single instance mutex handler (My application can be run only once).
    It use OS default property where single UDP port can be bind only once at time.
    """

    @staticmethod
    def enable():
        """
        By calling this you bind UDP connection on specified port.
        If binding fails then port is already opened from somewhere else.
        """

        try:
            AppMutex.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)  # UDP
            AppMutex.sock.bind(("127.0.0.1", 40000))
        except OSError:
            raise Exception("Application can be run only once.")
```

Simple call at begining of your script:

```
AppMutex.enable()
```

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by the answer from [Juan Leni here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43834075/check-if-a-particular-python-script-is-already-running), I extended the code a bit

```py
import os
import psutil
import sys


def check_if_script_is_running(script_full_path, compare_full_path=True, raise_error=False, verbose=False) -> bool:
    """
    Checks if a script is already running. Optionally raises an error if it is.

    Parameters:
    -----------
    script_full_path: str
        The full path to the script that we want to check if it's running.
        Can also be just the script name - but might be prone to errors, if a script with the same name is executed from a different folder.

    compare_full_path: bool, optional
        If True, the function will compare the full path of the script_full_path input with any parameter called on a python executable
        If False, the function will compare only the filenames to find python instances running the same script.

    raise_error: bool, optional
        If True, the function will raise an Exception if the script is already running.
        If False, it will only print a warning message and return a boolean value.

    verbose: bool, optional
        If True, the function will print messages indicating the comparisons and the results.

    Returns:
    -------
    bool
        True if the script is already running, False otherwise.
    """

    # Get the filename without the (if provided) full path
    script_name = os.path.basename(script_full_path)
    amount_of_already_running_instances = 0
    list_pids = list()
    i = 0  # an iterator to make verbose printing more readable

    if verbose:
        print(f"Checking if an instance of '{script_name}' is running.\n")

    for q in psutil.process_iter():
        if "python" in q.name():
            for parameter in q.cmdline():  # returns every parameter that the python.exe was started with
                if parameter.endswith(script_name):
                    # this is the parameter the script name
                    # depending on the way the script was called initially, this can be a full path (or not)
                    i += 1

                    if compare_full_path:
                        if verbose:
                            print(
                                f"comparison {i} - full path:\n{parameter} (parameter)\ncompared with \n{script_full_path}  (__file__)\n")
                        if parameter == script_full_path:
                            amount_of_already_running_instances += 1
                            list_pids.append(q.pid)

                    else:
                        parameter_script_name = os.path.basename(parameter)
                        if verbose:
                            print(
                                f"comparison {i} - filename only:\n{parameter_script_name} (parameter) \ncompared with \n{script_name}   (__file__)\n")

                        if parameter_script_name == script_name:
                            amount_of_already_running_instances += 1
                            list_pids.append(q.pid)

    if amount_of_already_running_instances > 1:
        err_msg = f"Script {script_name} is running {amount_of_already_running_instances} instance(s)\n" \
                  f"Only 1 instance of the script is allowed\n" \
                  f"Process IDs: {str(list_pids)}"

        if verbose:
            print(err_msg)

        if raise_error:
            raise Exception(err_msg)
        else:
            return True

    if verbose:
        print(f"Script '{script_name}' is running {amount_of_already_running_instances} instance(s)\n")

    return False


if check_if_script_is_running(__file__):
    sys.exit(0)
```

calling the function with `check_if_running(__file__)` will check if the this script is already executed in another python environment - as `__file__` is the fullpath to the script being executed right now.  Calling the function with the keyword `raise_error=True` will raise an Exception instead of returing a boolean value.

Be aware that, if the the other script instance was not called with a fullpath, it might be the more reliable way to use the keyword `compare_full_path=False` to find find a running instance, as only the filenames are compared.

You can also use this function to check if any other script is running, but you have to alter the behavior at `if amount_of_already_running_instances > 1:` a bit.